# Excel Pivot Table Counts the Numbers, but does not Display number as Discrete value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Software: Excel

Application: Pivot Table

I create table in Excel

[image]

I convert to Pivot Table, but it does not display number of files detected

[image]

I tried toggling through all the value field settings, but no success

[image]

Help!

Comment: First, you should use Sum instead of Count under "Value Field Settings". Second, could it be that values in "# Files detected" column are text not numbers?

Comment: @user11222393 I made sure values are Numbers, not Text. And I changed from Count to Sum. Now all 0s are displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your pivot table has value field setting as count. That means for each month for each year, you only have 1 value. If you look at 2022, it has the count as 8. That is because you have 8 values in 2022, 1 value per month. This does not look at the actual amount of the value. You will need to switch the value field setting to sum. When sum is selected, it will sum all values for each month for each year. If you switch the pivot table to "sum of files detected" and it does not fix it, I would try two things. The first thing I would do is restart my computer and Excel. Sometimes excel pivot tables do not update even if you change a setting. It is a bug I face every once in a while. If that does not work, I would delete the pivot table and create a new one. Source for sum value in pivot table https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-values-in-a-pivottable-9ee73790-646a-42c9-9fc7-e1ca30096d9c

As user11222393 suggests, it is possible your data is not considered numbers in Excel. You will need to select all the values in "files detected" and change the number format to "Number". It is possible the format is "Text" or "General" https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @waluigiwah I restarted my machine and typed in new numbers and set value field to sum. It worked. Then I copied and pasted the numbers. I made sure it was "Numbers". It didn't work. Now i manually typed in the numbers and it works. But why can't this glitch be fixed?

Comment: @Marium This is a common issue with Excel. Can you look at the bottom right of the number cell and see if there is a green flag? If there is a green flag, hover over the cell, click on the flag warning, and click convert to number. You can do this for the whole column by selecting the column and then doing the steps above. If that is not available, my last resort is putting the numbers in Google Sheets. Convert the values to number if it did not automatically do it. Then, download the sheet and open it in Excel. Excel will now treat it as numbers and this always works for me.

Comment: @waluigiwah there was no green flag

Comment: Ok. Did you try uploading to google sheets, converting it to number there, then downloading it into excel?